# Wcf service exception good practices

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I am developing a distributed application. In it, there are roles and sets of permissions that I must validate.
Is a good pratice to throw an **exception**, in per example, **unauthorized access**?
Or should I send some message back to the client?

Comment: once you know that user is unauthorized, you dont want to execute any further code in any condition, so throwing exception is good.

Comment: is it really good to throw an exception? 

To quote Oreilly.Programming.WCF.Services.3rd.Edition:
Chapter 6 Faults:
"Concepts such as
exceptions and exception handling are technology-specific and should not transcend
the service boundary. In addition, attempts by clients to handle errors invariably lead
to increased coupling." But we are definetely arguing over this in my company

Answer (score 59, accepted):

On your service operation, you can specify a ***FaultContract*** that will serve both purposes like so:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(MyServiceFault))]
void MyServiceOperation();
```

Note that MyServiceFault must be marked with DataContract and DataMember attributes, in the same way you would a complex type:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyServiceFault
{
    private string _message;

    public MyServiceFault(string message)
    {
        _message = message;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get { return _message; } set { _message = value; } }
}
```

On the service-side, you are then able to:

```
throw new FaultException<MyServiceFault>(new MyServiceFault("Unauthorized Access"));
```

And on the client-side:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (FaultException<MyServiceFault> fault)
{
    // fault.Detail.Message contains "Unauthorized Access"
}
```

Comment: For the OP: you don't want to "throw exceptions". You want to "return faults". That's what this answer shows you how to do.

Comment: I, personally, believe that is the most elegant approach. Delegating to the WCF to show what to do with an exception. Thank you

Answer (score 14):

Well, you can catch all exceptions in the WCF service implementations methods and rethrow them as FaultExceptions. By doing it this way, the exception will be rethrown on the client with a message of your choosing:

```
[OperationContract]
public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
{
    try
    {
        ... code to retrieve customers from datastore
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception including stacktrace
        _log.Error(ex.ToString());

        // No stacktrace to client, just message...
        throw new FaultException(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

To avoid having unexpected errors relayed back to the client, it's also a good practice to never throw Exception instances in code on the server-side. Instead create one or more of your own exception types and throw them. By doing so, you can distinguish between unexpected server processing errors and errors that are thrown due to invalid requests etc:

```
public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
{
    try
    {
        ... code to retrieve customers from datastore
    }
    catch (MyBaseException ex)
    {
         // This is an error thrown in code, don't bother logging it but relay
         // the message to the client.
         throw new FaultException(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // This is an unexpected error, we need log details for debugging
        _log.Error(ex.ToString());

        // and we don't want to reveal any details to the client
        throw new FaultException("Server processing error!");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Yakov: A class from the logging framework of your choice. The logging code is mainly there to illustrate how you can have different logging for different kinds of errors. If you're looking for a good logging framework, have a look at log4net. Very mature and easy to use.

Comment: Can someone comment why this answer is not upvoted more and why the accepted answer is somehow better? It's more complicated and achieves the same thing?

Comment: @Esko: As far, as I understand, these answers use the very same functionality: SOAP-Fault by throwing a FaultException. The only difference is, that this answer only throws a base FaultExeption while the accepted answer shows how to customize the FaultExeption. The customization enables you to handle different types of server side exceptions more specific on client side and pass more informations. You can compare throwing FaultExeption vs. throwing FaultException<MyServiceFault> with throwing Exception vs. throwing MyCustomException in an non WCF-context.

Answer (score 3):

Throwing general Dot Net Exceptions would make the service client proxies and the server channel to go in faulted state if you are not using **basicHTTPBinding** ...To avoid that you should always throw **FaultException** from the service...
from you catch block just use:

```
throw new FaultException("Your message to the clients");
```