# C# Async Await In WCF 4.5 and Exception handling

Tags: wcf, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-await

In WCF .net 3.5 i used the asynchronous way with IAsyncResult Begin/End operation pattern.
When i had an exception, I would return a DataContract named ErrorData.
Also, I Could use the FaultContract.

In WCF for .net 4.5, How do you handle exception ?
I saw this guide:  [Wcf service exception good practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647615/wcf-service-exception-good-pratices)

Is this relevant to .net 4.5 ? If my WCF Service catches an exception, Do I return a FaultContract ?
I could not find good references for this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still do need to throw a `FaultContract`. I have an example on [my blog post "Async WCF Today and Tomorrow"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-wcf-today-and-tomorrow.html) - note that when that blog was written, "today" meant using the Async CTP and wrapping the `async` implementation in `IAsyncResult` methods. So the "today" approach no longer applies. The "tomorrow" section is the one that shows how to do it with `async` in .NET 4.5.

Comment: Do you mention anywhere how to recover from a WCF fault state of a proxy/service ? (i use Channel with ChannelFactory.CreateChannel)

Comment: A regular `FaultException` is an exception from the service and doesn't need recovery. If you have an actual WCF (e.g., communications) fault, I believe you'd have to recreate the channel. I only have experience with proxies, myself.

Comment: Yes, Unhandled exception on service side, in managed application, would cause the channel to become fault. also in client side, if channel is open too long or other things, would cause the channel to be faulted, in IIS enviroment, the IIS will recover, on managed applications i didnt find good pattern/practices for recovery.